# Vite - "Source map points to missing source files"

Tags: reactjs, vite

All of a sudden I'm getting this error for practically all modules installed.

Sourcemap for "C:/.../node_modules/.vite/react.js" points to missing source files
Sourcemap for "C:/.../node_modules/.vite/axios.js" points to missing source files
Sourcemap for "C:/.../node_modules/.vite/react-dom.js" points to missing source files
Sourcemap for "C:/.../node_modules/.vite//react_jsx-dev-runtime.js" points to missing source files

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ic-logistic",
  "version": "0.0.0",
    "proxy": "http://localhost:8080/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react-map-gl": "^6.1.17",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "sass": "^1.42.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^1.0.0",
    "vite": "^2.6.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change `@vitejs/plugin-react` version from `"^1.0.0"` to exact version `"1.0.5"`. You can read more about this error in this thread: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/5438

Answer (score 2):

Extending @nefaris answer, what solved it for me was replacing v1.0.x with 1.0.8 :

```
npm install @vitejs/plugin-react@1.0.8 --save-dev
```